# How do I modify a src within an iframe?

Tags: iframe

I use a SaaS app which includes a tracking option for my customers, however I would really like this info to be available on my website

The tracking page can be accessed via url, so with the help of Google and this site, I've been able to create my own search box and display the results in an iframe.

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" id="TrackingFrame" src=""></iframe>
```

And a search box with a script...

```
<form onSubmit="return process123();" method="post">
<input type="text" id="TrackingNumber">
<input type="submit" value="Track">
</form>
```

```
function process123()
{
var url="http://www.3rdPartySite.com/Tracking.aspx?Number=" + document.getElementById("TrackingNumber").value + "&ID=123456";
document.getElementById("TrackingFrame").src=url;
return false;
}
```

This is working well except that there is a header on the page I would like to remove, and adding #name-of-id to the url has not been reliable.

I've setup a 2nd document with a 2nd iframe and give the div a negative margin to crop off the part I don't want displayed.

My question is, how do I get the above script to modify the src within the child document?
I have tried a few other answers I found, including...

```
document.getElementById('TrackingFrame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('TrackingFrame2').src=url;

document.getElementById('TrackingFrame').innerDoc.getElementById('TrackingFrame2').src=url;
```

...but neither of these options are working.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Unfortunately, your parent and child page must match each other as required by [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). What site is this specifically? UPS? FedEx? There are many corporations and services that have an API that allows developers access to services programmatically.

Comment: Yes, I did read about that policy, but I don't believe it applies to this situation. In this case, both the parent and child are on the same domain, and even in the same directory. I am not trying to access or modify anything on the external site, only add a url to the iframe in the child document, from the parent document.

This is specialty software that allows the customer to track the status of their order. The results are more detailed than what you might get from UPS/FedEx. I've been told that an API may be possible but that I would need to pay for part of the development cost.

Comment: So you own `http://www.3rdPartySite.com/`? Is this child page an iframe to `http://www.3rdPartySite.com/` and then the parent page has an iframe to the child page?

Comment: There are 3 pages involved, and the first 2 are mine. The parent would contain an iframe to my 2nd page, and the 2nd page would contain an iframe to the the external site. The purpose of the 2nd frame is to add a negative margin on the top and the left, cropping that portion of the external site. However, with the url for the external site now defined in the child document, that is the one I would need to change. -- If there is another, better way to do this, I'm open to anything.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

OP request for the ability to use the <kbd>ENTER/RETURN</kbd> key, so the button `type` is now `submit` and the `eventListener()` has been changed as follows:

```
/* Register the <form> on the submit
|| event. When user has submitted data
|| into by the [ENTER] key or clicking
|| the button, the callback function...
*/

qForm.addEventListener('submit', eventHandler);

function eventHandler(e) {         

  /* if the [ENTER] key was clicked or the
  || submit event occurs...
  */
  if (e.keycode === 13 || e.type === 'submit') {

    /* ...gets the value of the textbox
    || then invokes tracker function and
    || passes the value of the textbox.
    */
    var query = qForm.elements[0].value;
    tracker(query);
  }
  // Prevent post to server
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

---

---

This demo is just a partial nonfunctional example since SO security prohibits most iframe features for security reasons (I haven't bothered to test it because 90% of the time iframes will not work, that goes for YouTube examples as well) So I have provided a functional demo at [**Plunker**](http://embed.plnkr.co/ELcymKG9MUG9CHvQHpEe/). The url of course is different, I'm sure you can figure out how to substitute yours in.

**Details are commented within the demo**

## [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/ELcymKG9MUG9CHvQHpEe/) (Functional)

### Demo (Nonfunctional)

```html
<form>
  <input>
  <input type="button" value="Track">
</form>
<iframe width="90%" height="auto" id="subFrame" src="sub.html" scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>

<script>
  // Reference the <form>
  var qForm = document.forms[0];

/* Register the <form> on the submit
|| event. When user has submitted data
|| into by the [ENTER] key or clicking
|| the button, the callback function...
*/

qForm.addEventListener('submit', eventHandler);

function eventHandler(e) {         
  
  /* if the [ENTER] key was clicked or the
  || submit event occurs...
  */
  if (e.keycode === 13 || e.type === 'submit') {

    /* ...gets the value of the textbox
    || then invokes tracker function and
    || passes the value of the textbox.
    */
    var query = qForm.elements[0].value;
    tracker(query);
  }
  // Prevent post to server
  e.preventDefault();
}

  function tracker(Q) {
    /* This url is a Template Literal
    || ${Q} is a interpolated expression,
    || ${Q} is just like ' + Q + '
    || Instead of quotes ' and ", it uses
    || backticks ` (top left corner of 
    || keyboard)
    */
    var url = `http://vocaroo.com/media_command.php?media=${Q}&command=download_mp3`;

    /* Reference the iframe's document with
    || the .contentDocument property
    */
    var iSub = document.getElementById('subFrame').contentDocument;

    /* Reference the 2nd iframe by the
    || reference of the iframe document
    */
    var iTrkFrame = iSub.getElementById('trkFrame');

    // Set the .src property to url value
    iTrkFrame.src = url;
    return false;
  }
</script>

<!--===================[sub.html]========================

  <iframe width="90%" height="auto" id="trkFrame" src="about:blank" scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>
  
=======================================================-->
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work, and same-origin doesn't appear to be an issue for me.
However, there are two things I'm hoping can be improved.
1) It appears that we are registering "form", but not a specific one, so I had to remove my other forms from the page for this to work. Can we do this by ID instead?
2) This solution uses "button" instead of "submit". Previously, I could enter a number and press enter OR click the button. In this case, pressing enter will reload the page, and only clicking the button will run the process.

Comment: @Josh Your'e welcome. 1) `document.forms['ID'];` 2) Yes I believe so, try changing the `change` event to `submit` and just revert the button back to the original one or change `type` to `submit` on the new `<button>`. I had changed the event from `submit` to `change` because the demo would need a server to post to and I didn't want to add an extra layer abstraction to it, I have a tendency to over do things to the point of burying the heart of the answer in too much code.

Comment: 1) Perfect, that is working now! -- 2) I had tried changing the "button" to "submit" earlier, and now I've tried a few options with "change" changed to "submit" but the results are the same. The button reloads the page just like pressing enter does, or neither do anything.

Comment: I have an idea, do you know if you actually post anything to a server, because the form in the OP (Original Post) has the `<form method='post'....` but no `...action='server url'...>`. But if `submit` event isn't posting to any server, then I code show you how to add a key event to bind to the return button

Comment: Nope, nothing is actually posted to the server. `method="post"` can be removed.

Comment: LOL it did? I just retested the code and I couldn't get it to work now 0_0 ... I think I better backtrack on the Plunker versions. Well I'm relieved you got the correct code before I mucked it up. :) What the hey? It works again, I better quit while I'm ahead, anyways happy coding.